# An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection". java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using

- eclipse.buildId=4.24.0.I20220607-0700
- java.version=11.0.17.
- BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=aarch64, WS=cocoa

Error: An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection". java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z

This error occurred after downloading the Oracle WebLogic Server Tools plugin (17.3.0.201903121357) on eclipse.

From what I've found, it's probably because there are two versions of ICU4J, and the 72v only has this method `boolean isSurrogate(int codePoint)` and not `boolean isSurrogate(char char16)`.

[image: Two versions of icu4j installed]

Does anyone know how to fix this without upgrading eclipse to 4.25? As it seems like 4.24 is the most recent version that supports Java 11.

I've already tried deleting the ICU4J 72 plugin manually but it removes maven from my eclipse.

Full error logs:

> An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaWordFinder.findWord(JavaWordFinder.java:39)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.updateOccurrenceAnnotations(JavaEditor.java:3300)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.lambda$4(JavaEditor.java:3363)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup.calculateASTandInform(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:175)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionListenerWithASTManager$PartListenerGroup$1.run(SelectionListenerWithASTManager.java:151)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

> Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaWordFinder.findWord(JavaWordFinder.java:39)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.updateOccurrenceAnnotations(JavaEditor.java:3300)
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor$ActivationListener.windowActivated(JavaEditor.java:1216)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$8.run(Workbench.java:1005)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.fireWindowActivated(Workbench.java:1002)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$6.shellActivated(WorkbenchWindow.java:2459)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:92)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4604)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1547)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1528)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowDidBecomeKey(Shell.java:2314)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6373)
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:229)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.becomeKeyWindow(Widget.java:390)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.becomeKeyWindow(Shell.java:533)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6092)
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSWindow.close(NSWindow.java:57)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.destroyWidget(Shell.java:819)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:1373)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.release(Control.java:2970)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:695)
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.close(Window.java:335)
> at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.close(Dialog.java:988)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.close(InternalDialog.java:651)
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.handleShellCloseEvent(Window.java:739)
> at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TrayDialog.handleShellCloseEvent(TrayDialog.java:220)
> at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window$1.shellClosed(Window.java:685)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:102)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4604)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1524)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1547)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1532)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.closeWidget(Shell.java:624)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowShouldClose(Shell.java:2518)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6278)
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.callSuper(Widget.java:236)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowSendEvent(Widget.java:2162)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowSendEvent(Shell.java:2487)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:6405)
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSendSuper(Native Method)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationSendEvent(Display.java:5653)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.applicationProc(Display.java:5792)
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend(Native Method)
> at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSApplication.sendEvent(NSApplication.java:117)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3963)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
> at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
> at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
> at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
> at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
> at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
> at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

Answer (score 4):

4.25 and 4.26 both support *developing* for Java 11, they just have components that require Java 17 to run properly. You can download a compatible JDK from https://adoptium.net/temurin/releases/ .

If there's a newer WebLogic plug-in, you should also get that. Version 17.3.0.201903121357 indicates a build from 2019.

Comment: Hi Nitin, thank you for your suggestion. I've tried running JVM 11 on 4.26 using the -vm option but I received this error: "Version 11.0.17 of the JVM is not suitable for this product, Version 17 or greater is required." I've also tried 4.25 using JVM 11 but maven does not appear in the eclipse IDE under preference or run as.

Comment: The suggestion was to use Java 17 to run Eclipse, not Java 11. This doesn't prevent you from developing for Java 11.

Comment: Ah i see, I didn't know the difference. So to develop for Java 11, I just need to go to preferences -> Java -> installed JREs -> select Java SE 11.0.17? and change the JDK compliance compiler compliance level to 11?

Comment: Yes, although you can also set those at the project level so that you have more flexibility when working with more than one project.

Answer (score 2):

Very frustrating.  I'm getting this error in a little box.

"An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z"

I minimize the error box. It drops to the lower left corner of the screen, and everything seems to work fine. Will research this later.

Comment: Sadly, that is what I'm doing too, by shifting the error box offscreen. I was unable to upgrade my eclipse ide as I need to use Java 8 for my weblogic server

Comment: This helps but we won't be able to use shortcuts like "Ctrl + O" to open quick outline :-(

Comment: This SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76041611/2459449 should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Menu window > Settings > Java > Editor > Mark Occurrences
Disable "Mark occurrences"