# 'boolean com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(char)'

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse

An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
'boolean com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(char)'
"Requesting Java AST from selection"

I installed Spring Tool Suite in Eclipse. Although I uninstalled the tool,the error is still there. What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpWTv.png)

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Comment: Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: 2022-03 (4.23) as well, Enterprise Java package

Answer (score 30):

**--Solution 1** : Go to : **window** > **preferences** > **java** > **Editor** > **mark occurrences** and disable : **mark occurrences ...**

**--Solution 2 (deeply recommended)** : if you need to use **mark occurences**, use **eclipse 2022-12 and this will fix the error**. Then choose the type of ide that you want, if you use JEE dowload **Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 2022-12**

Comment: to know more about **mark occurnces** you can read [the documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/mark_occurrences.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Check the plugins folder of your STS installation.  In my case a plugin I had installed and downloaded a newer version of the com.ibm.icu class (v71) which has a different signature than v67.1 which includes issurrogate method.  Even after uninstalling the plugin the newer class was still there - actually both versions were - so I continued to get the isSurrogate error.  After deleting the v71 class from my plugins folder the problem disappeared and I was able to leave Mark Occurrences enabled.  This is the version I left in my plugins folder com.ibm.icu_67.1.0.v20200706-1749.jar

Comment: Unfortunately, by removing the indicated file, the Help->"Eclipse Marketplace..." option disappeared, although the problem was resolved. Re-entering the file didn't fix it, I had to reinstall Eclipse.
Personally, I do **not** recommend this method.

Answer (score 4):

I had to remove the following jar:
com.ibm.icu_72.1.0.v20221115-2007.jar
From my plugins directory on windows:

> C:\Users\USERNAME.p2\pool\plugins

Comment: i dont see this path on my end. :c
tried the c:\Users\<username>\.p\plugins

Answer (score 3):

I was having this exact issue, but was happening even when opening a .java file.

While disabling Mark Occurrences worked I do depend on the feature enough to still want it enabled. In my search, while uninstalling every plugin one at a time to test them.

I uninstalled the plugin:

`m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP    1.2.1.20150819-2220`

and after this, i no longer received the error. If you have this plugin installed try uninstalling it.

**Eclipse Info:**

- Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
- Build id: 20220609-1112

**Installed Plugins:**

- Buildship Gradle Integration 3.0
- Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle 2033.6.13a
- EGradle Editor 3.1.0
- Groovy Development Tools 4.7.0 RELEASE
- JAutodoc 1.15.0
- m2e-apt 1.5.4

Comment: Removing m2e-wtp unfortunatelly did not help me

Answer (score 2):

After removing v7x (newer version) of com.ibm.icu jar from plugins folder and restarting the STS helped me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Where did you find that file?

Comment: It should be here: `<YOUR_STS_DIR>\plugins\*`.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko it was in the eclipse folder. <Eclipse folder>/plugin

Answer (score 0):

spring tool suite--- select window option ion tab and than preferences > java > Editor > mark occurrences and disable mark occurrences in checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I'm using eclipse version 2022-06, and ran into this same problem.

I just updated the pluggins and IDE, and it solved itself.

At the top bar menu, go to,
**Help > Check For Updates**

Answer (score 0):

This might be outdated, but for anyone still looking for answers, you might want to check that you have a good "com.ibm.icu_xxxxxxxxxxx.jar" in your plugins dir to begin with.

Recently transfered over from Windows to Linux, reconfiguring Eclipse (same version 2020-06) I encountered this error on the Linux side. Turns out, the jar in linux and windows versions are somehow a mismatch;
Copying manually from the windows eclipse config solved my problem with said error

"An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z"