# while am open the Eclipse getting in this of error message

Tags: java, internals

An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".

[image]
can't be able to clear this error. repository also not getting old version first appall we suspect to the error message is populate reason is not installed SVN Repository, but this is not repository error message.

Comment: Please be more specific what you do to trigger this error. Just start the IDE without a project, or open a project, or ...? Also add the versions of Eclipse and Java that you use with all details you can find out. Did it work before? What did you change?

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74779212/an-internal-error-occurred-during-requesting-java-ast-from-selection-java-la

Comment: we find the solution to yesterday. Try anyone got this error message go to Eclipse main menu window => preference => java > occurred